# Sql constraint on boolean field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Is there is a possibility to make SQL constraint for the boolean field? I want to make a constraint that will check all record and only 1 record can have boolean field checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this,

```
_sql_constrainst =[('your const. id', 'check(your_bool_field != Null)', 'Your validation msg')]
```